# Workaround for unsupported positional operator in MongoDB C# driver for .NET core

Tags: linux, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

It seems all usages of positional operators in the C# driver is unsupported when running .Net Core on Linux.

Here is an issue I reported to the MongoDB team, that unfortunately hasn't got much attention:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2066

While we're wating for this to be fixed, does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: The driver is open source so you could effectively try and fix that issue yourself! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can resort to using JSON string based queries. So using the example you gave in the JIRA issue which looks like this:

```
collection.UpdateOne(
    filter: Builders<Animal>.Filter.Where(x => x.Subdocument.Subarray.Any(itm => itm.SomeProperty == "foobar")),
    update: Builders<Animal>.Update.Inc(x => x.Subdocument.Subarray[-1].SomeNumericProperty, 10)
);
```

You could rewrite this as:

```
collection.UpdateOne(
    filter: Builders<Animal>.Filter.Where(x => x.Subdocument.Subarray.Any(itm => itm.SomeProperty == "foobar")),
    update: "{ $inc: { \"Subdocument.Subarray.$.SomeNumericProperty\": 10 } }")
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I had to replace the comma before the 10 with a colon.